# Removing version from Maven dependency filename in war file

Tags: maven

I'm stuck with a problem where I have several external dependencies in Maven.

I have third-party libraries that together form a release of a product. The third party product does not use maven or supply a pom file, so I'm stuck with a collection of coupled .jar files, which I don't know the exact coupling of, other than that they all belong together.

Say I have these files:

- mail.jar
- pe.jar
- xpp3-1.1.3.4.M.jar

They are all part of the same 'version' of the product, say version 2.0. When I build this project with maven, I get in /target/MyProject folder and the MyProject.war file, the files with the following names:

- mail-2.0.jar
- pe-2.0.jar
- xpp3-1.1.3.4.M-2.0.jar

How can I tell maven to exclude those version tags during the build, so that I get these filenames in my final build?

- mail.jar
- pe.jar
- xpp3-1.1.3.4.M.jar

I have looked at maven-war-plugin:2.2 -> , the default:

`<outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.artifactId}-${artifact.version}${dashClassifier?}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>` -> Throws error: Failed to copyt file for artifact [..]: Invalid argument

Also, my version...
`<outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.artifactId}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>`

...gives strange filenames:

`com.foo.bar-${artifact.artifactId}.${artifact.extension}` (no extension, no translation of properties)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I'm even later, but as there isn't a correct answer yet...

When you build a WAR artifact, and you want the dependency JARs which land in target/${finalName}/WEB-INF/lib not to have the version number in the file name, then you can use

```
<outputFileNameMapping>@{artifactId}@@{dashClassifier?}@.@{extension}@</outputFileNameMapping>
```

in the configuration of `maven-war-plugin`.

Answer (score 0):

You are going the wrong way. Deploy them to your local Nexus instance and declare them as a dependency in your project's POM. Hint: XPP3 and mail.jar are already available in Maven Central. Do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: That's not an answer to my question. This is an example, I have 20 libraries, somehow dependent on eachother, delivered with a third-party product. The wheel has already been reinvented by the supplier. They are declared in my POM, but the result of this POM is that my resulting libraries now have the value of <version> in their names. I want to get rid of that.

Comment: What is the exact problem having those version numbers in the filenames?

Answer (score -2):

I'm late to the party, but I believe what you want to do is this.

```
<build>
  <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
</build>
```

Comment: That will change the name of the war, not the libraries inside the .war, which is, I believe, what he is asking for.